# App crashes when minimized when dialog is open

Tags: android

I'm using Searchable spinner (https://github.com/miteshpithadiya/SearchableSpinner) and whenever the spinner dialog is open and I click the home button or anything to minimize my app, the app crashes with the following error code:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: com.package, PID: 21974
                                                                       java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.toptoche.searchablespinnerlibrary.SearchableSpinner)
                                                                           at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1468)
                                                                           at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1416)
                                                                           at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:686)
                                                                           at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1330)
                                                                           at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1079)
                                                                           at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:711)
```

My adapter:

```
//Initializing Spinner
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.name);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> nameAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.name, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(nameAdapter);
```

What's wrong? Is there any way to fix it "outside" the package?

Comment: can you please add the full stacktrace? Often, the top errors which seems to be the cause are just caused by another error. So I guess there is more inside the stacktrace....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it is an issue with the library as other users reported the same issue on Github. You'll need to use a workaround [such as this](https://github.com/miteshpithadiya/SearchableSpinner/issues/21#issuecomment-242924948) for dismissing the SearchableListDialog in onPause().

EDIT: in SearchableListDialog.java:

```
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        dismiss();
        super.onPause();
    }
```

Comment: I saw this, but the solution posted there is not applying to me, as where `dismiss();` comes from? I get `can't resolve dissmis()` wherever they use it

Comment: To clarify: dismiss() is part of the SearchableSpinner  class so you need to access it through your reference, you can't just call dismiss() outright.

Comment: I've been trying that, but the `spinner` class has no method `dissmiss()`. Look here: http://i.imgur.com/CMEeBIi.png

Comment: My bad, it looks like the bug is with the SearchableListDialog class, not with SearchableSpinner itself. You can get around this by manually importing the library and overriding onPause with the dismiss (like the users on Github issues suggested). Here is the class that needs to be fixed https://github.com/miteshpithadiya/SearchableSpinner/blob/master/searchablespinnerlibrary/src/main/java/com/toptoche/searchablespinnerlibrary/SearchableListDialog.java You might want to send a pull request to the library author, it seems like a pretty big oversight.